# Hi guys i am working on my final year project on blockchain tecnology using etherium i havent benn able to get free ethers please help

Tags: go-ethereum

I have tried every means to get some free testnet ether for my etheerium blockchain final year project for testing please guys help me with some testnet ether 0x521F137871082aAF01EEC7E10C70315d588A7772

Comment: Which testnet are you on?

Comment: please i'm on rinkeby testnet

Comment: not really...i just need some ether to test with

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straight forward, and fast, to get Ether on Rinkeby via the faucet.

In the spirit of ["teach a man to fish"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) - I'll help teach you what to do rather than send you Ether.

1. Create a Gist - similar to [this one](https://gist.github.com/stevejaxon/891ee1fde7c35ba5a83ae5af9911738d);
   that contains your Ethereum address
2. Copy the URL of the Gist from your browser's address bar
3. Navigate [the Faucet](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/)
4. Paste in the URL of the Gist into the big input box
5. Select the amount of Ether you want from the dropdown list (labeled "give me Ether")

And that's all there is to it.